# Not able to install APK after removing the device from Intune company portal

Tags: installation, apk, android-enterprise, microsoft-intune

After enrolling my Android device in the Intune company portal, I removed it from the company portal. Now, if I install any APK from other sources downloaded via Chrome, it keeps saying

> Unkown apps can't be installed by this user.

I tried to go to Settings -> Install unknown apps -> Files by Google -> Allowed, still the same error. Device admin apps are all off. Still getting the same error.

---

This may answer it:
https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/249737257/unknown-apps-can-t-be-installed-by-this-user

Comment: Have you tried asking the company whose portal you joined ?

Comment: May be In tune has created a new work profile (which is running as a different user profile in Android) and Chrome is still running in that work profile even if Inues has been removed? In that case the error message would make sense. The question is just how tk get back to the regular non-work-profile Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your Android Settings is different to mine.

- Go to `Settings`
- Press `Security and Privacy`
- Press `Install unknown apps`
- Toggle the switch for Chrome

[image]

Comment: I turn on Chrome, Files by Google, Drive. Not working. Turn everything on, not working either.